# Define the $Hom(V,W)$ by $\phi: V → W$ by $g\phi(v) = g\phi(g^{-1}v)$, show it's a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Define the $Hom(V,W)$ representation by $\phi: V → W$

by $g\phi(v) = g\phi(g^{-1}v)$

where

$\phi \in Hom(V,W) = {\{f: V → W}\}$ and $g\in G$.

Show that  $Hom(V,W)$ is indeed a representation/homomorphism.

attempt: Let  $\varphi_1 : G → GL(V)$ and $\varphi_2: G → GL(W)$ be representations.

Suppose for every $g_1,g_2 \in G, v \in V$, we have

$(g_1g_2)\phi(v) = (g_1g_2)\phi[(g_1g_2)^{-1}v] = (g_1g_2)\phi[(g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1})v] $

I am stuck. Can someone please help me?I need to show it's a homomorphism.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're defining a representation of the group $G$ on the vector space $Hom(V,W)$ after being given representations on $V$ and $W$, correct?

Comment: Yes. $\varphi_1 : G → GL(V)$ and $\varphi_2: G → GL(W)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a map
$$\rho: G \to GL(Hom(V,W))$$ by 
$g \cdot \varphi(v)=g\varphi(g^{-1}v)$. Let $\varphi, \psi \in Hom(V,W)$. Then for any scalar $c$ and vector $v  \in V$, we have
\begin{align*}
g \cdot (c\varphi+\psi)(v)&=g(c\varphi+\psi)(g^{-1}v) \\
&=g(c\varphi(g^{-1}v)+\psi(g^{-1}v))\\
&=cg\varphi(g^{-1}v)+g\psi(g^{-1}v) \\
&=(gc\varphi+g\psi)(v)
\end{align*}

The last two lines follow from the fact that $G$ acts linearly on both $V$ and $W$. Hence we have $g(c\varphi+\psi)=c(g\varphi)+g\psi$, implying $G$ acts linearly on $Hom(V,W)$.

For the next condition, we check $\forall g, h \in G$ we have $(gh)\varphi=g(h\varphi)$. Let $v \in V$. Then 
\begin{align*}
(gh)\varphi(v)&=(gh)\varphi((gh)^{-1}v) \\
&=(gh)\varphi((h^{-1}g^{-1})v)) \\
&= g(h \varphi(h^{-1}(g^{-1}v)))
\end{align*}
which is what we wanted.

If $e \in G$ is the identity, we clearly have $e \varphi=\varphi$, and so $\rho$ is a representation.

Comment: Thank you ! It's very helpful